# jquery - plugin bubble click event

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, event-bubbling

i'm trying to create my own jquery plugin but am having problems bubbling the event to the page (I think this is the problem).

I am calling the plugin like so.

```
$('div.testdiv1').bpcolourpicker
({
    onClick: onClickCallback
});

var onClickCallback = function ()
{
    //alert('testpage');
}
```

PLUGIN CODE-

```
    var defaults =
    {
        returncolour: 'ff0000',
        showtextbox: true,
        onClick: function () { }
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);



    var onClick = function ()
    {
        // default
    }

    // Select a colour
    $(thisdiv).find('div.bpcolourpicker table.colours div').click(onClick, function ()
    {
        var divtitle = RGBToHex($(this).attr('title'));
        $(thisdiv).find('input#chosencolour').val(divtitle);
    });
```

So what I want to happen is when the click method is fired, I want to bubble that event to the main page as i'm calling 'onClick: onClickCallback' so I would have thought onClickCallBack would handle the event.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you want to call `options.onClick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `onClickCallback` before you set the variable.

Your code is failing the same way as

```
alert(num);
var num = 3;
```

If you change the callback to a function *statement*, such as`function onClickCallback() { ... }`, it will work.  Function statements are usable before their definitions, unlike normal variables.

---

Also, you cannot add two event handlers by passing two parameters to `.click()`.
Instead, you should explicitly call `onClick()` from your handler.

Comment: Ah ok, I swapped them but it's still not firing that function.

Comment: Rookie mistake - I have now changed it to a function and calling it like so
    $('div.testdiv1').bpcolourpicker
            ({
                onClick: onClickCallback
            });

and also taken out the onclick parameter from the event oh and at the end of that event i'm calling onClick but its not working :(

Comment: @code: As @sje397 pointed out, you need to call `options.onClick`.

Comment: ok, i've put in options.onClick at the end of my click event - still nothing.